# Cocoa Touch Framework not recognised

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a Utility Cocoa Framework, a class with a bunch of utility methods. I use this framework in several other app, without any problem. I just created a new app, and app is not able to recognise methods. Any idea why? I have not upgraded Xcode.

[image]

Embedded library set:

[image]

`Utility` method is public:

[image]

I have go though on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86cPaa3FrRg

Answer (score 0):

ahh, .. I forget to select to run on Device, simulator not an option for me

[image]